# Change reference of class level variable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

We have a class:

```py
class Parent:
    A = 1

def print_a(self):
   print(Parent.A)
```

I want to create another class inheriting the first one and change the class variable:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    A = 2
```

Now, when I am executing:

```py
example = Child()
example.print_a()
```

It prints '1'.

How to change reference of class variable A in a Child class (in print_a function)? I don't want to copy the whole print_a function replacing Parent.A .

**The important thing, that I am not able to edit Parent class in this case.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the @classmethod decorator

this should work as expected:

```py
class Parent:
    A = 1

    @classmethod
    def print_a(cls):
        print(cls.A)


class Child(Parent):
    A = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Child.print_a()
    e = Child()
    e.print_a()
 
    # Child.A is not inherited from parent
    Parent.print_a()
```

output:

```
2
2
1
```

if you want to set the variable in parent:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    Parent.A = 2
```

Comment: I am not able to edit Parent class. Maybe, there are some other ways to create instance of Parent class and change A just for instance?

Comment: Like I showed, You can change it with `Parent.A=2` in `Child`.
Then your original code should work.

Comment: The problem is that if we have instances of Parent class, Parent.A = 2 affects them..

Comment: You could also override the print_a method in the child class (perhaps make it a @classmethod as the parent should have been)